# Missing selecting text after copy text in Flutter on IOS

Tags: flutter, dart

When you copy text on IOS in native apps the selecting text is remains. But in flutter the selecting text is missing such as in android native app. I'm using cupertinoTextField but problem is stay on.

Comment: [Video with the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JWJ_xsYNQPgBpbEynoPTPW5YekrUGQha/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I has opened an issue on flutter github.